# Whats the difference between [01], [0-1] and [0,1] in linux globbing?

Tags: linux, glob

Title, is there a reason to use one and not the other in X case?

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls 192.168.[0,1].1
192.168.0.1  192.168.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# ls 192.168.[01].1
192.168.0.1  192.168.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# ls 192.168.[1].1
192.168.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# ls 192.168.[01].1
192.168.0.1  192.168.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# ls 192.168.[0-1].1
192.168.0.1  192.168.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# ls 192.168.[10].1
192.168.0.1  192.168.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# ls 192.168.[01].1
192.168.0.1  192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `[...]` is part of the filename expansion set. The three examples you give are all different, but in some cases two of them can be equivalent:

- **`[01]`:** this matches the character `0` or `1`
- **`[0,1]`:** this matches the character `0` or `1` or `,`
- **`[0-1]`:** this is a range expression, any character that falls between those two characters (`0` and `1`) will be matched. This depends on the current locale and the values of `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_ALL`. If `LC_ALL=C`, the range `[0-1]` and the set `[01]` will be equivalent.

This pattern is used in a filename expansion, this implies that if you would have a file named `192.168.,.1` it would have been matched with `[0,1]`.